# Arrows to explain table header

Tags: tikz-arrows

In [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162417/how-can-i-check-the-permissions-of-a-specific-group) StackOverflow answer we can see the diagram below.

[image: diagram]

I'd like to know how to do this in Tikz. I'd rather not have the boxes and have arrows pointing towards the values right below the headers, but these are details that I can probably manage if I have something to work from.

Comment: I am finding it more difficult to follow the lines to the labels than I would like. Perhaps different colours for neighbouring lines would make it easier to read.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I do plan to make some improvements. My table is different anyway. I will only have one line per column, not one per character.

Comment: I think it would be as clear, and simpler to type it with \threeparttable` – no arrows needed, only table notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult to draw this but tedious to punch in all these things from a screen shot (which is why I just added `can 1` and so on, you can replace these texts by whatever you find more appropriate).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,node distance=2pt and 4pt]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=top]
  \node (c1) {d};
  \node[right=of c1] (c2) {l};
  \node[fit=(c1) (c2),label=above:type]{};
  \node[right=1cm of c2] (c3) {r};
  \node[right=of c3] (c4) {w};
  \node[right=of c4] (c5) {x};
  \node[fit=(c3) (c5),label=above:users]{};
  \node[right=1cm of c5] (c6) {r};
  \node[right=of c6] (c7) {w};
  \node[right=of c7] (c8) {x};
  \node[fit=(c6) (c8),label=above:groups]{};
  \node[right=1cm of c8] (c9) {r};
  \node[right=of c9] (c10) {w};
  \node[right=of c10] (c11) {x};
  \node[fit=(c9) (c11),label=above:others]{};
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {int(12-\Y)},
 remember=\Z as \LastZ]
  in {can 1,can 2,can 3,can 4,can 5,can 6,can 7,can 8,can 9,can 10,can 11}
  {\ifnum\Y=1
   \node[anchor=north west] (l\Z) at ([xshift=1em,yshift=-1ex]top.south east) 
    {\X};
  \else
   \node[anchor=north west] (l\Z) at ([yshift=-0.2ex]l\LastZ.south west) {\X};
  \fi
  \draw[latex-] (c\Z) |- (l\Z);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I propose an entirely different layout, using only `\tablenotes` from `threeparttable` combined with colours, which is, in my opinion, as expressive as arrows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\dir}{\textcolor{Goldenrod}d}
\newcommand{\syl}{\textcolor{LightSteelBlue}l}
\newcommand{\rd}{\textcolor{Salmon}r}
\newcommand{\wri}{\textcolor{Gold}w}
\newcommand{\exc}{\textcolor{YellowGreen}x}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering\sffamily
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Table}
  \label{}
\begin{tabular}{*{4} {>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}}}
\toprule
type & users & group & others \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}
\dir \enspace\syl & \rd\enspace\wri\enspace\exc & \rd\enspace\wri\enspace\exc& \rd\enspace\wri\enspace\exc \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, online]\small
\item[\dir\rlap{:}] Is a directory.
\item[\syl: ] Is a symbolic link.
\item[\rd: ] Can Read,\, Read files.
\item[\wri: ] $\!\!$Can Write,\, Create files.
\item[\exc: ] Can Execute,\, List files.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]